# Rich text input into limited length text field in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

In Access 2010, I have somehow configured a front-end form and back-end table that is allowing "rich-text" data input into a plain text field in a back-end database.

The table field is defined as a text field, 255 characters long. When the data in the field is viewed directly, it takes the form: `<div>&nbsp;P2 &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>` which is what I'd expect for an Access "rich-text" field.

The field bound to this table field is a text-box with text-format Plain text (!). There is no validation or code associated with it. When I enter or edit text in this field, I can apply text formatting to it.

In many ways, this is very useful -- I have a rich-text field that is limited to 255 characters in length. However, sorting and filtering shows the underlying HTML-markup, so has to be disallowed, and I'm sure there are other drawbacks.

However, my users like it well enough that they've asked for the same functionality elsewhere in the application... and I can't work out how I did it. I suspect I was trying out memo fields versus plain text fields for this particular piece of data and stumbled on a sequence of changes that led to this result.

I've tried cutting pasting and renaming the table and corresponding form fields to replicate it without success.

I've googled extensively for descriptions of similar situations -- no success.

Is there a way to replicate what I've achieved?

Comment: `MemoField` can take `rich text`.. Can you please re-confirm that you want to insert rich text into a text field?

Comment: @bonCodigo, I want a limited length rich-text field -- either a Memo field that is constrained to (say) 50 characters or a text-field 50 chars long that accepts and displays rich-text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a form with a text box bound to a rich text memo field, you can set a Validation Rule on that text box to limit it to 50 characters or less.

[image: text box property sheet to display Validation Rule]

However that length restriction will be based on the total count of all characters ... not just those displayed, but also the markup tag characters.  See this example from the Immediate Window:

```vba
? DLookup("memo_field", "tblFoo", "id =1")
<div>a <strong>b </strong>c</div>
? Len(DLookup("memo_field", "tblFoo", "id =1"))
 33
```

If you want to exclude the markup characters from the length limit, use the `PlainText()` function:

```vba
? PlainText(DLookup("memo_field", "tblFoo", "id =1"))
a b c
? Len(PlainText(DLookup("memo_field", "tblFoo", "id =1")))
 5
```

And in that case, the Validation Rule property could be this:

```vba
=(Len(PlainText([txtMemo_field]))<=50)
```

When you query the source data with a filter condition on that memo field, all the stored characters (including the markup tags) will be evaluated.  If you want the filter condition to ignore the markup tags, use the `PlainText()` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE PlainText(memo_field) = "a b c";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of characters with a little code. One example would be:

```
Private Sub txtText_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If Me.txtText.SelStart >= 254 Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I have not tested for the number of characters with Rich text.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out how I configured the front-end form and back-end table that is allowing "rich-text" data input into a plain text field in a back-end database.

I linked the front-end database to a test back-end that had the relevant fields set up as rich-text fields, then created/edited the relevant form (with field format as rich text).  I then relinked it to the production database which has exactly the same structure except the back-end fields were plain text.

I don't recommend it but it does work.