# How to work around Access VBA error 3188

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Having converted a number of fields in a table tblSource to Rich Text memos, I'm getting an error 3188 in the following circumstances.

Main form has a subform open (frmSource) bound to qrySource. qrySource pulls in some fields from tblSource and adds a calculated field which concatenates the (newly-minted) rich-text memo fields (SD1 to SD20) so that the result can be displayed in a single text box on frmSource called Citation.

If the user wishes to edit SD1 to SD20, they double-click on the Citation field and a modal form frmCitation opens up displaying the SD fields for editing. frmCitation is bound to qryCitation which pulls the SD fields and a couple of others out of tblSource.   When finished, they close frmCitation. When SD1 etc were text fields, the tblSource record was updated successfully. However, now they're memo fields, I'm hitting VBA error 3188 ("Could not update; currently locked by another session on this machine.").

Searching on the Internet suggests that this is a common issue with Rich Text memos when a memo  size exceeds 2k (limitation possibly due to Access edit buffer size?), so I'm looking for ways to work around it.

One option would be be to split tblSource into two tables tblSource and tblCItation with a one-to-one relationship between them, then base qrySource on tblSource and qryCitation on tblCitation, but that's fairly major surgery with knock-on effects in a number of other places in the application.

Another option is to limit the size of all the memo fields on this form (as per [Rich text input into limited length text field in Access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14124264/1943174)), but there's one field for which that wouldn't be acceptable to the users.

Is there another technique I could explore?

Comment: Are you sure  that the base form does NOT have a dirty record that you are launching from? Before you launch that edit form, place a me.Refresh right before the command that opens that form – any existing pending writes in the current form will thus be flushed.

Comment: @Albert Already in place -- you can't open the modal form if the base form is dirty.

Comment: I suppose you could use a un-bound text box. In the forms on-load event you pull the data from the memo using a recordset and then on form close/save you take the text and update the table via that recordset.  As noted, I would try this with row locking turned off and see if that helps. Unfortunately, I never encountered this error.

Comment: The solution by @AlbertD.Kallal to use a Me.Refresh of the form that called the popup form is what worked for me.  I tried the other solutions and workarounds mentioned below and none of them worked, but doing a Me.Refresh of the calling form before doing the Me.Dirty = False to save the record on the popup form solved the 3188 error.  Interestingly, though, it is only for Rich Text textboxes that have a Len of more than 2000 characters that requires the Me.Refresh to be done--if the textbox has a Len of less than 2000 characters, I get no errors when trying to save out the record.  Strange!

Answer (score 0):

Per the following MS Link:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/memo-field-could-not-update-currently-locked-by/d5c8163a-7ce5-484f-80d4-98c1a8c92160

near the bottom, they suggest the limit is 2,000 characters.
Not that it helps, but could you add code to the 'before update' to display what the new size should be wnen concatenated? May help to figure a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to save the form before making any changes with:

```
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
```

Workaround 1: Try to update not a field of an underlaying query or table, but a field of the form's Recordset. For example:

```
With Me.Recordset
    .Edit
    !MemoField = "TEXT ADDED HERE <- " & !MemoField
    .Update
End With
```

Workaround 2: If you need to update not form's Recordset, but any other Recordset, try to unbind the TexBox, make the update and then make the TextBox binded back again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I closed all other open tabs (tables, etc...) and tried again. That worked fine.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30869243)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem years ago & was revisiting in case it as not an issue anymore, but seems it is.
I had a list/column form of emails inc a field with a large rft memo.
I wanted to click on a record to bring up the one email in single form
The only way I could get it to work was Open the Single form & immediately close the multi row form, on exiting the single had to load the list again using bookmarks etc. to return to where I wanted to be, a real pain.
Especially as like now I would like to be able to access the the list whilst still on the single form, hence the revisit, instead looks like I will have to save all the list'id somehow. Dooable but a lot more programming that I think should be necessary.